# Weak star limit

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, banach-spaces

Let $\Omega = \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[$ and let a function $A_n: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ defined as:
$$A_n(x) = \begin{cases}\alpha &\text{if } k \epsilon \leq x < (k+\tfrac{1}{2}) \epsilon \\
\beta &\text{if } \big(k+\tfrac{1}{2}\big) \epsilon \leq x < (k+1) \epsilon
\end{cases} $$ 
for $k=0$, $1,\ldots,n-1$ where $\alpha$, $\beta > 0$ and $\epsilon=1/n$.

How can I compute the weak star limit for $A_n$ in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)?$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question: what is $k$ in your definition? You defined $A^\epsilon$, what is $A_n$? (Is this homework?)

Comment: $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and he is arbitrary. and $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: @jijiii I just made edits to that effect, but got interrupted before I had time to explain myself in a comment. Good to see that I guessed right.

Comment: Thank you so much Harald Hanch-Olsen;

Comment: We say that $A_n$ weak star converge to A if and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty}\displaystyle \int_0^1 A_n(x) g(x) dx = \int_0^1 A(x) g(x) dx$ for all $g \in L^1(]0,1[)$

Comment: and my problem is how i can compute $A.$

Answer (score 2):

Since $L_\infty(\Omega)=L_1^*(\Omega)$ you need to show that for all $f\in L_1(\Omega)$
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle A_n, f\rangle = \langle A, f\rangle\tag{1}
$$
where $A$ is the desired limit. In fact it is enough to check $(1)$ only for some functions $f\in S$, where $L_1(\Omega)=\overline{\mathrm{span}S}$. Now consider
$$
S=\left\{\chi_{[a,b)}:[a,b)\subset [0,1)\right\}
$$
Then for all $f\in S$ you have
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle A_n,f\rangle=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\int\limits_{(0,1)}f(t)d\mu(t)
$$
Now you can suggest what is $A$.

Comment: Yes, even better to use step functions than continuous functions, as I did (I knew this, but forgot). But I think you could just let $S$ be the set of characteristic functions of *any* interval; your choice can lead to confusion regarding the roles of $k$ and $n$ in the proof.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen thank this another one good improvement

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It is enough to compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 A_n(x)f(x)\,dx$$ for continuous functions $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, since these are dense in $L^1(\Omega)$. You will find that the limit is $$\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\tag{1}$$ – just take the difference between the two integrals, consider the difference of integrals over each subinterval $[k\epsilon,(k+1)\epsilon]$, and use uniform continuity. (Perhaps you wish to insert a Riemann sum in the estimate.)

**Edit:** For more detail, note $$\int_0^1 A_n(x)f(x)\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\Bigl(\alpha\int_{k\epsilon}^{(k+1/2)\epsilon}f(x)\,dx+\beta\int_{(k+1/2)\epsilon}^{(k+1)\epsilon}f(x)\,dx\Bigr)$$ in which you replace $f(x)$ in the integrals on the right by $f(k\epsilon)$, carefully estimating the error you introduce by doing so. (For any $\eta>0$ you can pick $\epsilon>0$ so that $\lvert f(x)-f(k\epsilon)\rvert<\eta$ for $x\in[k\epsilon,(k+1)\epsilon]$ – this is uniform continuity.) Now do the same with the integral in (1) and subtract.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't undersant two points.

Comment: Why $L_1(\Omega) = \overline{span} S?$
and why exactly $\lim_n < A_n,f> = \dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \int_0^1 f(t) d \mu (t)$?

Comment: My big problem is how we obtain that 
$\lim_n < A_n,f> = \dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \int_0^1 f(t) d \mu (t)$?

Comment: For the first one, that the continuous functions (or the step functions) are dense in $L^1$ (not $L^\infty$, as I mistakenly wrote in the original answer) is a standard result in measure and integration theory. You can find it in almost any book on the subject. For the step functions, it follows from [Littlewood's first principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_three_principles_of_real_analysis).

Comment: For the second one, I just added some more detail to the answer. Hopefully it is enough so you can do the rest on your own.

Comment: Step 1: Let $f$ a continuous function ( so it's not necessary to take $f$ in S) then, we have $\int_0^1 A_n(x) f(x) dx = \sum_{k=0}^n (\alpha \int_{k\epsilon}^{(k+1/2)\epsilon} f(x) dx + \beta \int_{(k+1/2)\epsilon}^{(k+1)\epsilon} f(x) dx)$

Comment: in step 2: we remplace in the integrals of the right hand $f(x)$ by $f(k \epsilon)$ and we find $\int_0^1 A_n(x) f(x) dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k \epsilon) [\alpha (k+1/2) \epsilon - \beta (k+1/2)\epsilon - \alpha k \epsilon + \beta (k+1)\epsilon$ 

How we can estimate $|f(x) - f(kx)|$? and why we need to do this? and the big problem is how we obtain 1/2 in $\alpha + \beta /2$?
Help me please

Comment: Note that what you wrote as an equality here is not an equality, since you replaced $f(x)$ by something else. Subtract the right answer from the almost right answer: That is where you need the estimate, to find out how big the difference can be. The $1/2$ comes from the fact that each of the two integrals are over an interval only $\epsilon/2$ long, instead of $\epsilon$. Sorry, I don't have the time for further detail. If you need a complete solution with all details filled in, maybe someone else will oblige.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand this method and i don't have a other method. Thank you so much , but i need a more details to understand this method help me please i will be crazy

Comment: Please help me to understand this solution

Comment: please tell me why $\int_0^1A_n(x) f(x) dx = \dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \int_0^1 f(x) dx?

Comment: There is no equality there, except in the limit. As I said before, I really don't have more time for this. Sorry about that. Perhaps you should post a new question asking for clarification on this? There are plenty of people capable of helping, but this question will have dropped below anybody's radar by now.