# Limit and integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Let $\Omega = \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[$ and let a function $A_n: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ defined as:
$$A_n(x) = \begin{cases}\alpha &\text{if } k \epsilon \leq x < (k+\tfrac{1}{2}) \epsilon \\
\beta &\text{if } \big(k+\tfrac{1}{2}\big) \epsilon \leq x < (k+1) \epsilon
\end{cases} $$ 
for $k=0$, $1,\ldots,n-1$ where $\alpha$, $\beta > 0$ and $\epsilon=1/n$.
Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. How can we prove that  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 A_n(x) f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\alpha \int_{k \epsilon}^{(k+1/2)\epsilon} f(x) dx + \beta \int_{(k+1/2)\epsilon}^{(k+1)\epsilon} f(x) dx\right) \\= \dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \int_0^1 f(x) dx$$
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: Use that $f$ is in fact uniform continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is uniform continuous on $[0,1],$ so for all $\eta > 0,$ there exist $\epsilon > 0: |f(x) - f(k \epsilon)| < \eta$ for all $x \in [k \epsilon,(k+1)\epsilon]$ but how we can use thise to compute the limite?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this question is about clarifying my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351005/weak-star-limit). I could not find the time to go into the necessary detail, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. All you need to prove is that
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k/n}^{(k+1/2)/n} f(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
   $$
2. Remember that (Riemann's sums theorem)
   $$
   \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}f(k/n)\,dx = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
   $$
3. By using the uniform continuity of $f$, you can justify an estimate of the type
   $$
   \int_{k/n}^{(k+1/2)/n} f(x)\,dx \simeq \frac{f(k/n)}{2n}
   $$
   for large values of $n$, uniformly in $k$.

---

**Extension to the case $f\in L^1[0,1]$**

Use the density of continuous functions in $L^1[0,1]$ and the fact that for all $n$ we have
\begin{equation}
\left|\int_0^1A_n(x)f(x)\,dx - \int_0^1A_n(x)g(x)\,dx\right| \leq \max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\} \|f-g\|_{L^1}
\end{equation}

hence
$$
\left|\langle A_n,f\rangle - \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\int_0^1 f\right| \leq C_{\alpha,\beta} \|f-g\|_{L^1} + \left|\langle A_n,g\rangle - \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\int_0^1 g\right|
$$
where $C_{\alpha,\beta}=\max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}+\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$.

Thus, for every $g$ continuous we have (according to what you did in the first part)
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\langle A_n,f\rangle - \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\int_0^1 f\right| \leq C_{\alpha,\beta} \|f-g\|_{L^1}
$$
and $\|f-g\|_{L^1}$ can be made as small as necessary, so finally
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|\langle A_n,f\rangle - \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\int_0^1 f\right| = 0
$$

Comment: Okay! I think that i'm understand. $f$ is continuous on a compact so she is uniformly continuous so for all $\eta > 0$ there exist $\epsilon > 0$ : $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

Comment: for $y = k \epsilon,$ we have $|f(x) - f(k \epsilon)| < \eta$ i.e., $f(x) \simeq f(k \epsilon)$ so $\int_{k \epsilon}^{(k+1/2)\epsilon} f(x) dx \simeq \dfrac{f(k/n)}{2 n}.$
and for the Riemann's sums theorem, $\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int f(x) dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_0^1 f(x) dx.$ And we could de conclude.

Comment: My last question is: how we can prouve this relation for all $f \in L^1(0,1)$?

Comment: Let $g \in L^1,$ then, there exist a sequence $(f_m)_m $ of continuous functions such as $f_m \rightarrow g$ dans $L^1.$  So $\lim_{m \rightarrow + \infty} A_n(x) f_m(x) dx = \int_0^1 A_n(x) g(x) dx.$
Then, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} \lim_{m \rightarrow + \infty} \int_0^1 A_n(x) f_m(x)dx = \dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \lim_{m \rightarrow + \infty} \int_0^1 f_m(x) dx = \dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2} \int_0^1 g(x) dx = \lim_n \int_0^1 A_n(x) f_n(x) dx.$$
correct?

Comment: It's true, we must justify the inversion of limits.What's the uniformity with respect to $n$ please?

Comment: The inequality I gave you in the last part of my answer is uniform in $n$. Now, you can also see how to use this.

Comment: How we can pass to a limit in $g_m$ in the last relation??? he is no $g_m$